# Only not received email on my particular domain email address using PHP email code

Tags: php, email

I have `my domain on 1and1` and `hosting on godaddy`. Now, i created email account on `1and1 my domain account`.

I received `email on my 1and1 email account` from directly send on any email but its not work for me using PHP code to send email.

Below is my PHP code:

```
  $to = 'support@mydomain.com';
    $_POST['from'] = "Get a free quote - ";
  $subject = $_POST['from'].'Inquiry from Website';
  $message = " Hello, <br><br>
  This is test email. <br><br>
  Thanks";

  $headers = 'From: Quotes <harsh08@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

If i change my domain email to my gmail then i received email on gmail account using above code.

I tried lot but did not get any solutions still. Anybody have a knowledge or experience in it then please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: I have used that 1and1 host that needs SMTP details for outgoing emails.Try with that

Comment: Not for outgoing but need to receive email in my 1and1 email.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spam and spelling of  email address. Sometimes mail servers detect mail as spam.

Comment: Checked both but not issue in spell and not received in span. Thanks

Comment: I think it will be better to write  in the comments area instead of answer like your.Only try to answer if you have exact details,